# Struts 2:How to load values to a <s:select >from a list in session

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am new to struts. I want to load a list of data in the session to a select tag `<s:select>` which equals to pure html `<select><option>values..</option></select>` . The data might be loaded from database and put them to a list. I looked for Internet. But it all didn't work for me. Please any one let me know how to do this or provide any link with working example.(  including the action class,struts.xml and jsp page. most needed codes are enough.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the list of values in a java.util.List on the stack, you should be fine with something like this:

```
<s:select label="Some label"          
list="yourList"
name="somName" />
```

You can find a sample here: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. W.Goeman. One thing: this loading must be done at the time of jsp page directly loading. (that means, when the user request this jsp page, this `select` must be loaded.) At the first time of jsp page loading (request doesn't come to the action class.directly call to the jsp page) , the list(util.List) must be loaded and set to session or request,then the `select` must be loaded with data.Does that sample address my requirement? or any suggesion.

Comment: @AashMaharoon, the example behind that URL totally addresses that. 
Struts works as follows: The user requests the page. This triggers the action class. In the example, the constructor of the action class populates the list. That will be your DB call. The execute method of the action class returns SUCCESS, which will start the rendering of the page, with the data in the list.

Comment: @AashMaharoon, as I think you are confused about struts works: note that you do not request the page in your browser, but you request the action class. It happens to be the case that if execute returns SUCCESS, that jsp is used. It could as well have been a different one. That is defined in the struts.xml file.

Comment: Once again,thank you for your advice and appreciate. Actually I m new to Struts and learning(I m confidene with JSP Servlets and may be I look at strusts as same as JSP Servlets). You mentioned : `note that you do not request the page in your browser, but you request the action class.` do you mean that we don't call jsp pages but the action class ? then, web page's navigation bar(Menu bar) has showSomthingAction.action intead of showSomthingAction.jsp( <a href"showsomthingAction.action">Buy</a>) ?

Comment: @AashMaharoon, you are welcome. You are absolutely right there. The idea of struts is to translate the URL (blabla.action) into a Java class, and depending on the result (SUCCESS), render the applicable jsp file. So indeed, your browser will be pointing to blabla.action, and not to a jsp.

Comment: Thanks Mr. W. Goeman. As I mentioned before that I m still new to struts,I want to confirm this further. Then, Should any navigation or requesting jsp page that would be created with dynamic data be called to its action class's name? Lets say, there is a page called 'clients.jsp' and in normal jsp page is called in a link/navigation is <a href="clients.jsp">Our Clients</a> . But in strusts we have to write it  '<a href="ClientAction">Our Clients</a>'  Here  the name 'ClientAction' is mapped to a java class called 'ClientListingAcion' and it is declared in struts2.xml file.  am I right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12630/discussion-between-w-goeman-and-aash-maharoon)

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to place List in the session?
Struts2 provides a clean way to put your request/response data in Valuestack and its OGNL system provides a very clean way to access those data from the value stack.All you need to have a list in your action class with its getter and setters and at UI use build in struts2 tag to access those data.Here is a simple code to accomplish this

### Action Class

```
public Class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

  private List<String> myList;
  //getter and setter for myList

  public String execute() throws Exception{
    myList=new ArrayList<String>();
   // fill the list
   return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

At UI level you need to use S2 [select tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/select.html) like

### JSP

```
<s:select label="MyList"
       name="myList"
       headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Value"
       list="myList"

/>
```

This is all you need to do. For mapping this in struts.xml its quite straight forwards and all you need to configure your action name and its respected class.Hope this will help you.
For more details about S2, i suggest to refer official doc.

Still if you want to put the list in session in your java class and want to access it in jsp here is the JSP code

```
%{#session.MyList}
```

- [Struts 2.3.1 Documenation](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/home.html)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Umesh Awasthi. I use session to store some values to reduce the database hits. I ll try as you mentioned.

Comment: make sure you set list in Session inside your action class