# <s:select> option diaplay object address

Tags: jsp, struts2, java-web-start, case-sensitive, struts-tags

I am using struts2 to translate list to JSP, but the `<s:select>` option display object address rather than object property of name, why?

My display :

[image]

This is JSP :

```
<s:select  name="parentId" list="#departmentList" cssclass="SelectStyle" listkey="id" listvalue="name" >
```

This is DepartmentAction:

```java
public String addUI() throws Exception {
    List<Department> departmentList = departmentService.findAll();
    ActionContext.getContext().put("departmentList", departmentList);
    return "saveUI";
}
```

This is Department:

```java
private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;

private Set<User> users;
private Department parent;
private Set<Department> children;
```

Comment: The display com.hw.oasys.entity.Department@2fff3c24

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't good idea put your list directly to ActionContext, you can use Session for that, or better list with getter/setter in you action class.
For better understanding you can look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053256/struts-2how-to-load-values-to-a-sselect-from-a-list-in-session)

Answer (score 0):

Case matters:

1. `listkey` != `listKey`
2. `listvalue` != `listValue`
3. `cssclass` != `cssClass` (and in recent Struts2 versions you can just use `class`)

```xml
<s:select  name = "parentId" 
           list = "#departmentList" 
       cssClass = "SelectStyle" 
        listKey = "id" 
      listValue = "name" />
```

P.S: You're not encountering errors due to dynamic attributes allowed on the tags.